# Android: Handle error case when reading from local database?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to read entries from a local database and show it in some kind of list view.

In case of no entries I show an empty state UI.

I'm wondering if I need to add an error state UI. Can the local database be unreachable or can read errors occur?
(Programming errors excluded - in these cases I want the app to crash to become quickly aware of it.)

*Clarification*:
I might mention UI too much in my question. I'm only interested in what database errors can occur when reading from a local database, which are not caused by programming errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ListView, will be empty, if the source of the ListView (Cursor or Array) is empty (rather than null which would result in a null pointer exception). In fact in most cases the ListView will initially be empty as you'd typically call setContentView which applies the layout, which would typically include the ListView (which at that stage has no adapter and thus nothing to display). You would then get the ListView, setup the adapter and then set the ListView with the adapter, which would then result in the items being listed (if any).

An SQLite database, once created is pretty solid and the chance for read/write errors is pretty slim and I'm pretty sure an exception would be raised.

The most frequent read errors, as such, are when copying a pre-existing database and generally the cause is the directory into which the database file is placed doesn't exist.

- The Database is create outside of the App and generally placed into the assets folder, the asset *(which is read only and also compressed)* is then copied to where it will be fully accessible (generally in the databases directory of the App's data (*data/data/package_name/database/the_database_file*)

Comment: thanks for your answer. the interesting part for me is this: "An SQLite database, once created is pretty solid and the chance for read/write errors is pretty slim"
Does it mean you would catch errors but not put any effort into extra UI for this scenario but show the empty list?

Comment: @PeterF considering *I'm only interested in what database errors can occur when reading from a local database, which are not caused by programming errors.* then yes. These would be rare, the most common would be corruption of the db file, often due to bad programming. It may also depend. An example where I would trap errors, is when restoring a database from a backup, in which case the code would revert to the pre-restore version of the database (never been due to read/write error, in fact had to force an error to test (used a non SQLite file to restore from)).